# Keras Input layer seems to remove one dimension of the training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to construct a Parallel CNN with some convolution layers that get concatenated and fed through a Dense layer.

The summary looks like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
timestep_input-0 (InputLayer)   [(None, 11, 14, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
timestep_input-1 (InputLayer)   [(None, 11, 14, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
0_conv_layer_0 (Conv2D)         (None, 11, 14, 32)   832         timestep_input-0[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
1_conv_layer_0 (Conv2D)         (None, 11, 14, 32)   832         timestep_input-1[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
0_conv_layer_1 (Conv2D)         (None, 11, 14, 64)   51264       0_conv_layer_0[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
1_conv_layer_1 (Conv2D)         (None, 11, 14, 64)   51264       1_conv_layer_0[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
0_conv_layer_2 (Conv2D)         (None, 11, 14, 128)  204928      0_conv_layer_1[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
1_conv_layer_2 (Conv2D)         (None, 11, 14, 128)  204928      1_conv_layer_1[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_concatenate (Concatenate)  (None, 11, 14, 256)  0           0_conv_layer_2[0][0]             
                                                                 1_conv_layer_2[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
combine_concatenate (Conv2D)    (None, 11, 14, 18)   4626        conv_concatenate[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 2772)         0           combine_concatenate[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_regress_output (Dense)    (None, 2)            5546        flatten[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 524,220
Trainable params: 524,220
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

My problem is to do with the inputs. I have 2 input layers, 20000 pieces of training data, each of them of size 11x14 and just one 1 channel.

I understand then that the model.fit() X should be of the shape (2, 20000, 11, 14, 1) and I have 2 output nodes so my y should be of the shape (2, 20000, 2).

However when I run the fit(), I get

`WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 11, 14, 1) for input Tensor("timestep_input-0:0", shape=(None, 11, 14, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 20000, 11, 14).`

Followed by the error:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer 0_conv_layer_0 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 20000, 11, 14]`

So to me it seems like the last dimension of the training data gets somehow lost. Any help in figuring out how to somehow shape it so that it would work would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:
The model code as requested in comments:

```
    inputs = []
    parallel = []

    # make a list of inputs and parallel CNNs for the timestep consideration
    for p in range(TIME_WINDOW_SIZE):
        input_layer = Input(INPUT_DIM, name='timestep_input-{}'.format(p))

        x = Conv2D(filters=CONV_FILTERS[0],
                   kernel_size=CONV_KERNEL_SIZES[0],
                   strides=CONV_STRIDES[0],
                   activation=CONV_ACTIVATION_FUNCS[0],
                   padding='same',
                   name='{}_conv_layer_{}'.format(p, 0))(input_layer)

        for layer in range(1, CONV_LAYERS):
            x = Conv2D(filters=CONV_FILTERS[layer],
                       kernel_size=CONV_KERNEL_SIZES[layer],
                       strides=CONV_STRIDES[layer],
                       activation=CONV_ACTIVATION_FUNCS[layer],
                       padding='same',
                       name='{}_conv_layer_{}'.format(p, layer))(x)
        inputs.append(input_layer)
        parallel.append(x)

    # add the parallel layers together
    if TIME_WINDOW_SIZE > 1:
        x = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='conv_concatenate')(parallel)

    x = Conv2D(filters=CONV_CONCAT_FILTER,
               kernel_size=CONV_CONCAT_KERNEL_SIZE,
               strides=CONV_CONCAT_STRIDE,
               activation=CONV_CONCAT_ACTIVATION_FUNC,
               name='combine_concatenate')(x)

    x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)

    for i in range(DENSE_LAYERS - 1):
        x = Dense(units=DENSE_SIZE, activation=DENSE_ACTIVATION_FUNC, name='dense_regress_layer_{}'.format(i))(x)

    x = Dense(DENSE_OUTPUT, activation=DENSE_ACTIVATION_FUNC, name='dense_regress_output')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[x])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
                  loss='mse',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Post the model code, maybe you need Conv3D?

Comment: you have to reshape X  (2000, 11, 14, 1) like this. And if you have 2 input layer fit the model like this model.fit([X1, X2], y, epochs = epochs)

Comment: I mean, what you suggested is exactly what I put in, [X1, X2] is then of the shape ```(2,20000,11,14,1)```